# How to cache pages on Jquery mobile android[WebView]?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have made an app using DreamWeaver and the available Jquery scripts. I have uploaded them on my website. I load the *index.html* file on my app using the `loadURL()` function for WebView. Everything is working good.

The problem is I have to download all the files/images every time I start the app. Is there a way where I need to download the files only once and cache them on my mobile.

I know about the assets folder most people use. But for some reason Jquery doesn't work on the Lollipop android webview. It works when I uninstall the lollipop android webview. But I cannot expect my users to do that.

The screen just looks like this:

> [image: The screen just looks like this]